# Parameterized unit test suites

Tags: java, junit, testng, test-suite

I am trying to set up some parameterized test suites, unfortunately without any luck so far.
I have two set of parameters, and I would like to run multiple test cases (they are in different classes) with all possible combinations. I tried to do it with JUnit4, but I am unable to set it up correctly. This would be my basic idea:

1. `TestSuite1.class` sets up one set of parameters, then it starts `TestSuite2.class`.
2. `TestSuite2.class` sets up the second set of parameters, then it starts the actual test(s) that will use both parameters.

Meanwhile it seems it is not possible to set up both `Suite.class` and `Parameterized.class` in the `RunWith` annotation at the same time (according to google, `Parameterized` extends `Suite`, I get usually "no runnable method found" message if I use.)

This is how my code looks like basically:

TestSuite1.class:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@Parameterized.SuiteClasses({TestSuite2.class})
//I have tried with @RunWith(Suite.class) and
//@Suite.SuiteClasses({TestSuite2.class}) annotations also - all combinations
public class TestSuite1{

  public TestSuite1(int number) {
    Params.first = number;
  } 

  @Parameters
  public static Collection<Object[]> parameters(){
    Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 }, { 4 } };
    return Arrays.asList(data);
  }
}
```

`TestSuite2.class` looks the same as `TestSuite1.class`, except that I have added `TestCase1.class` to the suite instead of `TestSuite2`, and that it sets another variable in `Params`.

TestCase1.class:

```
public class TestCase1 {    
  @Test
  public void test1(){
    System.out.println("first: "+Params.first+" second: "+Params.second);
    Assert.assertTrue(true);
  }
}
```

I am open to all ideas - even with TestNG for example. I have tried it also (although today was the first time I saw it), but as I noticed the suites are a bit different than in JUnit. I would prefer not to set up XML files before testing, I would like to solve all set up programmatically.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible with any framework?

---

Update: With TestNG I have the following code:

Start.class:

```
public class Start {

public static void main(String[] args){
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { FirstTest.class, SecondTest.class });
    testng.addListener(tla);
    testng.run();
}
}
```

Params.class:

```
public class Params {
@DataProvider(name = "param")
public static Object[][] createData() {
    Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { 1 }, { 2}, { 3}, { 4} };
    return data;
  }
}
```

FirstTest.class:

```
public class FirstTest {

@Test(dataProvider = "param", dataProviderClass = Params.class)
public static void printIt(int number){
    System.out.println("FirstTest: "+number);
}

}
```

`SecondTest.class` is the same as `FirstTest.class`. If I run this, it runs `FirstTest` 4 times, then it runs `SecondTest` 4 times. I would like to run `FirstTest` one time, and `SecondTest` one time also with the first set of parameters. Then I would like to run `FirstTest` and `SecondTest` one time, with the second set of parameters, etc.

I have tried to set setPreserveOrder(true), and tried all setParallel options also. On this way however the results are in kind of random order.

(It would be some selenium test. I am aware that tests should not depend on each other, but still it would be my desired way for this)

Answer (score 1):

Although `Parameterized` extends `Suite`, it behaves totally different - in disrespect of the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). This is because normally the constructor `Suite(Class<?>, RunnerBuilder)` processes the `@SuiteClasses` annotation. But `Parameterized(Class<?>)` replaces this behaviour with a processing of `@Parameters`.

If you want to combine the behaviour of `Suite` and `Parameterized` you have to look outside of JUnit 4. E.g. you could implement your own `Runner` like Adam Hawkes already mentioned in [another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29948651/193705).

I did the same by myself and cobbled a library together that provides you with a `ParameterizedSuite` Runner: https://github.com/PeterWippermann/parameterized-suite

A parameterized test suite looks like this:

```
@RunWith(ParameterizedSuite.class)
@SuiteClasses({OneTest.class, TwoTest.class})
public class MyParameterizedTestSuite {
    @Parameters(name = "Parameters are {0} and {1}")
    public static Object[] params() {
        return new Object[][] {{'A',1}, {'B',2}, {'C',3}};
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So basicly as far as I understand, what you want to do is to run a test with set of sets of parameters. That is possible with JUnit and that is why method annotated with @Parameters returns a Collection of arrays (in general a set of sets).

Look at this example:

```
import static org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TestCase1 {

    public TestCase1(int first, int second) {
        Params.first = first;
        Params.second = second;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> parameters(){
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { 1, 11 }, { 2, 22 }, { 3, 33 }, { 4, 44 } };
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        System.out.println("first: "+Params.first+" second: "+Params.second);
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Edit:
If you want to share parameters between multiple test you could use an abstraction in your test cases.

```
public class AbstractParametrizedTest {

    public AbstractParametrizedTest(int first, int second) {
        Params.first = first;
        Params.second = second;
    }

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> parameters(){
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { 1, 11 }, { 2, 22 }, { 3, 33 }, { 4, 44 } };
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }
}


@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TestCase1 extends AbstractParametrizedTest {

    public TestCase1(int first, int second) {
        super(first, second);
    }

    ...
}
```

However the best way to do it i think, would be to use TestNGs data providers. Take a look at example at section 5.6.2 and usage of static data providers
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Comment: My main question would be about suites.It works fine with one testclass (although on this way I need to create all combinations of the parameters, but that's not an issue of course)-but I would like to achieve this using suites.I have many tests in multiple classes, that I would like to organize into suites. And I would like to run these suites with these parameters, instead of setting up the parameters each time I start a new testclass.(It would be better to make a suite 50 times from the start to end instead of doing the first testclass 50 times, then the second testclass 50 times and so on)

Comment: I have updated my description with a bit of TestNG code what I have. It works easier than JUnit, but still not exactly the desired behavior. Any other suggestion maybe?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the goal of executing all test cases with the same parameters in sequential order, you would need a different `Runner` as this behavior is held in that class. You're in luck, as this is available in the [JUnit Toolbox Project](https://code.google.com/p/junit-toolbox/) with the `ParallelParameterized` class!

Comment: Could you please explain how this should work? I don't see how the behaviour of [ParallelParameterized](https://github.com/MichaelTamm/junit-toolbox/blob/master/src/main/java/com/googlecode/junittoolbox/ParallelParameterized.java) is different from `org.junit.runners.Parameterized`. Doesn't matter if I set the number of threads to 1, does it? And most important: That annotation is not applicable to a test suite as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Here some other suggest that seems to be much more flexible: [@RunWith(Enclosed.class)](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/experimental/runners/Enclosed.html)

In short:
Instead of `@Suite.SuiteClasses(...)`, just use `@RunWith(Enclosed.class)` and extend your Test Classes

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class FastTest {

    public static class Test1FirstAppInit extends AppInitTest {    }

    public static class Test2Download extends DownloadTest{    }

    public static class Test3OtherTest extends OtherTest {    }
}
```

Now with Parameterized:

```
@RunWith(Enclosed.class)
public class FastTest {

    private static Iterable<? extends Object> mAllLocale = Arrays.asList(Locale.ENGLISH, Locale.GERMAN);
    private static Iterable<? extends Object> mSingleLocale = Arrays.asList(Locale.ENGLISH);

    /*
    Run test class for all Locale
     */
    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public static class Test1FirstAppInit extends AppInitTest {
        @Parameterized.Parameter
        public Locale mLocale;

        @Parameterized.Parameters
        public static Iterable<? extends Object> data() {
            return mAllLocale;
        }

        @Override
        public Locale getLocale() {
            return mLocale;
        }

        @Override
        public void test001ResetAll {
            assumeTrue(false); // skip test completedly
        }


        @Override
        public void test002ClearAppData() {
            // replace existing test
            if (getLocale() != Locale.ENGLISH) {
                /*
                should run only on first Locale
                skip test on following Parameter runs
                 */
                assumeTrue(false); // skip test
            }
            else {
                super.test000ClearAppData();
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    Run test class only for one Locale
     */
    @RunWith(Parameterized.class)
    public static class Test2Download extends DownloadTest{
        @Parameterized.Parameter
        public Locale mLocale;

        @Parameterized.Parameters
        public static  Iterable<? extends Object> data(){
            return mSingleLocale;
        }

        @Override
        public Locale getLocale() {
            return mLocale;
        }

        @Override
        public void test900Delete() {
            assumeTrue(false); // skip test
        }
    }

    /*
    Test not Parameterized
     */
    public static class Test3OtherTest extends OtherTest {    }
}
```

Your Test Classes for Parameterized tests look like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class DownloadTest {

    public Locale getLocale() {
        // will be overwritten in @RunWith(Enclosed.class)
        // but we are still able to run test class separatedly
        return Locale.ENGLISH;
    }

    @Test
    public void test900Delete() {
        ....
    }
    ....
}
```

Matches exactly what I was searching for. I can create different Test scenarios (full test, fast test,...). Just create different @RunWith(Enclosed.class) classes and extend the tests that you want to include.

Only side point seems to be that Enclosed.class does not care about sort order (if important to you).
I solved it by replacing Enclosed:

```
public class SortedEnclosed extends Suite {

    public SortedEnclosed(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder) throws Throwable {
        super(builder, klass, filterAbstractClasses(klass.getClasses()));
    }

    protected static Class<?>[] filterAbstractClasses(final Class<?>[] classes) {
        final List<Class<?>> filteredList= new ArrayList<Class<?>>(classes.length);

        for (final Class<?> clazz : classes) {
            if (!Modifier.isAbstract(clazz.getModifiers())) {
                filteredList.add(clazz);
            }
        }
        // this is new (there may be better way with own "@FixClassOrder"...):
        Collections.sort(filteredList, new Comparator<Class<?>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Class<?> o1, Class<?> o2) {
                return o1.getSimpleName().compareTo(o2.getSimpleName());
            }
        });
        //  
        return filteredList.toArray(new Class<?>[filteredList.size()]);
    }
}
```

And then use `@RunWith(SortedEnclosed.class)`