# How to parameterize junit Test Suite

Tags: java, junit4, junit-runner

Is it possible to parameterize a TestSuite in junit 4 ?

For declaring a class as a test suite I need the annotation `@RunWith(Suite.class)`, but the same annotation is also needed to declare the test as parameterized: `@RunWith(Parameterized.class)` so I cannot add both to the same class.

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891494/parameterized-unit-test-suites) in this site that did not help much. So far, all the examples I have found explain how to parameterize simple unit tests, not a complete test tuite.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the basic answer is No, because as you said, the @RunsWith only take one parameter.  I found a [blog posting that got a bit creative](https://www.google.com/search?q=junit%20@runswith&oq=junit%20@runswith&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.4823j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=junit4%20@runswith%20both%20spring) in how to handle this situation.

We don't use the parameterized tests, but may you could create a separate suite like we do that only lists the test classes and the parameterized test could be part of that.  I modified our test suite to include a parameterized test class to part of the suite and it ran fine.  We create our suite like below where PrimeNumberCheckerTest was a simple I pulled from the web.

```
package com.jda.portfolio.api.rest.server;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({  com.mycompany.api.rest.server.resource.TestCartResourceJava.class, 
                 com.mycompany.api.rest.server.resource.TestCustomerResource.class,
                 com.mycompany.api.rest.server.resource.TestWizardProfileResource.class,
                 com.mycompany.api.rest.server.interceptor.TestBaseSearchInterceptor.class, 
                 com.mycompany.api.rest.server.resource.TestQueryParameters.class, 
                 com.mycompany.api.rest.server.expression.TestCartExpressionGenerator.class, 
                 com.mycompany.api.rest.server.expression.TestPreferenceExpressionGenerator.class, 
                 com.mycompany.api.rest.server.PrimeNumberCheckerTest.class, 
                 })
public class AllTests {}
```

Here's the source for the parameterized test case;

```
package com.jda.portfolio.api.rest.server:

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
@SuiteClasses({PrimeNumberCheckerTest.class})
public class PrimeNumberCheckerTest {
  private Integer inputNumber;
  private Boolean expectedResult;
  private PrimeNumberChecker primeNumberChecker;

  @Before
  public void initialize() {
     primeNumberChecker = new PrimeNumberChecker();
  }

  // Each parameter should be placed as an argument here
  // Every time runner triggers, it will pass the arguments
  // from parameters we defined in primeNumbers() method
  public PrimeNumberCheckerTest(Integer inputNumber, 
     Boolean expectedResult) {
     this.inputNumber = inputNumber;
     this.expectedResult = expectedResult;
  }

  @Parameterized.Parameters
  public static Collection primeNumbers() {
     return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
        { 2, true },
        { 6, false },
        { 19, true },
        { 22, false },
        { 23, true }
     });
  }

  // This test will run five times since we have as many parameters defined
  @Test
  public void testPrimeNumberChecker() {
     System.out.println("Parameterized Number is : " + inputNumber);
     assertEquals(expectedResult, 
     primeNumberChecker.validate(inputNumber));
  }
```

Comment: -1 because I think you missed the point. Sergio wanted to parameterise the suite itself, not only execute a single, parameterised test

Answer (score 1):

I was able to parameterize a test suite and use its data in a test class member of the suite as follows:

In JUTsuite:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ 
    JUT_test1.class,
})

public class JUTSuite{  
    // Declare all variables/objects you want to share with the test classes, e.g.
    protected static List<Fx> globalFxs;
    // This is the data list we'll use as parameters
    protected static List<Dx> globalDxs;

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data(){
        // Instantiate object list for parameters.  
        // Note: you must do it here and not in, say, @BeforeClass setup()
        // e.g.
        globalDxs=new ArrayList<Dx>(serverObj.values());

        Collection<Object[]> rows=new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        for(Dx d:globalDxs) {
            rows.add(new Object[]{d});
        }
        return rows;
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        // Instantiate/initialize all suite variables/objects to be shares with test classes
        // e.g. globalFxs=new ArrayList<Fx>();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // Clean up....
    }
}
```

Next, in test class:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class JUT_test1 {
    // declare local names (if desired) for suite-wide variable/objects 
    // e.g. 
    private static List<Fx> globalFxs;

    // This is the test parameter:      
    private Dx d;

    public JUT_test1(Dx d){
        this.d=d;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data(){
    // Note: we're calling the suite's data() method which has already executed.
        return JUTSuite.data();
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    // (If desired)initialize local variables by referencing suite variables.
    // e.g.globalFxs=JUTSuite.globalFxs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain if `JUT_KB_integrity` is supposed to be a constructor or a setter?

Comment: Never mind, I corrected it. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it's not possible with the provided classes, but there are workarounds that will get you most of the way there, like @mikemil's.

I've spent some time extending Suite and delegating to Parameterized, with partial success; it is possible to build runner that does what you want, and the code is more-or-less written for you in those two classes.  The way those classes interact (in particular, the definition of `Parameterized#getChildren()`) makes it difficult to extend or delegate to those classes to accomplish what you need, but creating a whole new class than extends `ParentRunner` and lifts code from the other two would be fairly easy.

I'll try to get more time to come back to this later.  If you do build a new runner before I get around to it, please post it as an answer, I'd love to use it myself.

Comment: Did you find some time to do so in the meantime, Paul? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're right: Both `Suite` and `Parameterized` are Runners and only one `Runner` may be used to run a test at a time. Standard JUnit 4 doesn't provide a combined Runner.

You can either implement your own Runner or have a look at this ready-to-use library which provides a `ParameterizedSuite` Runner: https://github.com/PeterWippermann/parameterized-suite

A parameterized test suite looks like this:

```
@RunWith(ParameterizedSuite.class)
@SuiteClasses({OneTest.class, TwoTest.class})
public class MyParameterizedTestSuite {
    @Parameters(name = "Parameters are {0} and {1}")
    public static Object[] params() {
        return new Object[][] {{'A',1}, {'B',2}, {'C',3}};
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the best solution will be, keep suit classes separately in a blank class. 
For example, I am testing logins as Parameterized tests and putting in a suit (for navigation performance measurement)

```
     @RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
            LoginPageTest.class,
            HomePageTests.class})
    public class PerformanceTests {
    }
```

and LoginPageTest is actually Parameterizedtests

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class LoginPageTest
{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already stated multiple times, it's not possible to parameterize a test suite with the runners provided by `JUnit 4`.

Anyway, I wouldn't recommend to make your testclasses dependent from some externally provided state. What if you want to run a single testclass?

I would recommend to make your separate test classes `@Parameterized` and use a utility class to provide the parameters:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Test1.class, Test2.class })
public class TestSuite {
    // suite
}

@RunWith(Parameterized.class}
public class Test1 {
    public Test1(Object param1) { /* ... */ }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return TestParameters.provideTestData()
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest() { /* ... */ }
}

@RunWith(Parameterized.class}
public class Test2 {
    public Test2(Object param1) { /* ... */ }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return TestParameters.provideTestData()
    }

    @Test
    public void someOtherTest() { /* ... */ }
}

class TestParameters {
    public static Collection<Object[]> provideTestData() {
        Collection<Object[]> data = new ...;
        // build testdata
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer helps: [Parameterized unit test suites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20891494/parameterized-unit-test-suites/48840617#48840617)

It uses `@RunWith(Enclosed.class)` and seems to solve the problem.