# Configuration file to run JUnit Suite on different browsers in BrowserStack

Tags: java, selenium, configuration, junit, suite

Could you please look at my problem and give any advice to its solving.
I use JUnit4 and selenium 2 WebDriver.
So, I have class to run JUnit suite:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({className1.class, clasName2.class})
public class TestSuite
{
  public static TestSuite suite()
  {
      TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
      suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(className1.class));
      suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(className2.class));

      return suite;
   }
}
```

each class contains @Test method and extends BaseClass that sets in @BeforeClass parameters (through DesiredCapabilities) to run suite on BrowserStack machines:

```
public class MyTestBase{
    static protected WebDriver driver;
private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
protected static StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
            DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    capability.setCapability("build", "JUnit - Sample");
    capability.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", "true");
    capability.setCapability("browserstack.debug", "true");
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(
        new URL("http://username:accesskey@hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub"),
        capability);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    /* other code */
}
```

So, could you please help me with the next:
1) I need to create configuration file and use its parameters to run my TestSuite on different browsers in BrowserStack. Any examples of .xml file to do it will be appreciated.
2) And also how do I need to modify my TestSuite.class to use .xml file parameters.
3) My  TestSuite.class consists of many .class with @Test method in each. Each class extends MyTestBase.class where annotations @BeforeClass and @AfterClass are located, but when I run TestSuite new browser has been launched for each class in TestSuite and it's a very big problem for me. What can I do for running browser once for all @Test methods across all classes in TestSuite. I know that @BeforeClass works for all @Test methods inside one class, but what should be done if there are may classes? In TestNG there is @BeforeSuite solves this problem.
Sorry, for so many questions, but I've tried a lot and didn't succeed in this :(
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've never really seen a setup like this.. ever thinking about having something like Maven or Ivy build systems handle your tests, rather than a class dedicated to running the rest of the classes?

Comment: @PeterSmith thank you for your answer. Yes, previously I used ant to run my tests and it worked pretty good, but than I had only several test classes. For now, my Project gets bigger and I had refactored my code and decided to form Test-Suites that may be changed in time. How can I pass browser parameters to my TestSuite through ant commands in build.xml file? thanks

Comment: (who's PeterSmith??) have you seen this? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051705/how-to-parameterize-junit-test-suite

Comment: sorry for @PeterSmith =)

Comment: Have you considered using TestNG instead of Junit? Using TestNG you'll be able to store parameters in xml and pass them to the tests and launch browsers in @BeforeSuite annotated method.

Answer (score 0):

You asked a lot of questions concerning different topics. I will try to sort things out.

### Reusing a browser and not opening a new one for every test class

This can only be achieved if you instantiate your `WebDriver` once and use that object in all your tests. So don't instantiate your browser in the `@BeforeClass` method of your tests.

#### How do you initialise your `WebDriver`?

In the very first test class of your test suite. That might be a dedicated test just for opening the browser. Or you could include this functionality in all of your test and have to check, if the browser had already been initialised or not.

#### How to reuse a `WebDriver` object and share it between test classes?

I'd propose to create a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) that stores a `WebDriver` object. This way all tests can access it. However, it takes some more effort to make this thread-safe - in case your run your tests in parallel.

### Running your tests with different browsers

You should make your tests `@Parameterized` and expect a set of `WebDriver` objects as parameters to execute.

### Combining both: Different browsers and reusing browsers between tests

This will likely lead to a point where you would like to define parameters for your test suite. However, in standard JUnit 4 you can't do this.
I recommend to use the `ParameterizedSuite` runner from [this library](https://github.com/PeterWippermann/parameterized-suite).